# Exercise on determining the vectors that can be written as a linear combination of the columns of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise states

> Given $A_h = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> 2 & -2 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & h \\
> -1 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ determine the set of vectors  $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a  \\
> b  \\
> c  \end{array} \right)$ of $R^3$ such that they can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A_h$.

I have calculated that the determinant of $A_h$ is zero no matter what $h$ is chosen (the first row is -2 times the last row). So this tells me also that the columns of $A_h$ are linearly dependent, correct? this means that these columns can't span $R^3$ but how do I determine what they do span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved that the three vectors
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}, \text{ and }
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
h\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are linearly dependent. On the other hand, you can easily see that the first and second are linearly independent (*edit: as Bye_World mentioned in his comment, the third vector is a poor choice if $h = 0$*); moreover, if you sum them you get $\Big(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\Big)$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
-2\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
h\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle
&=
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
-1
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle\\
&=
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
2a\\
b\\
-a
\end{pmatrix}
: a,b \in \Bbb{R}
\right\}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ha, of course! Thanks for the catch, @Bye_World.

Comment: No problem. :-)